# Useful resources for configuring maven for hibernate and spring on eclipse

Tags: xml, hibernate, spring, maven

I want to configure maven for managing dependencies. What are the steps to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [appfuse](http://appfuse.org) using which you can create a skeletal spring-hibernate project, which can then be developed in eclipse using [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin